# Eigenfunction of LTI causal system Z-transform

Tags: impulse-response, z-transform

I am studying for my DSP final and I came across this question from the Oppenhiem and Schafer book 3rd edition. The question says

> **3.18** A casual LTI system has the system function
>
> $$H(z)=\dfrac{1+2z^{-1}+z^{-2}}{\left(z+\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}
> > \right)\left(1-z^{-1} \right)} $$
>
> **(a)** Find the impulse response of the system, $h[n]$
>
> **(b)** Find the output of this system, $y[n]$, for the input
>
> $$x[n]=e^{j(\pi/2)n} $$

For the first part, I got
$$h[n] =  -2 \delta[n]+\frac{1}{3}  \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^2 u[n]+\frac{8}{3} u[n]$$

which matches the answer at the back of the book, but the second part is difficult. We are asked to find the function $y[n]$ if $x[n] = 2^n$

I know that $2^n$ is an eigenfunction of $y[n]$, but I am not sure how to substitute it in $H(e^{j\omega})$. The answer at the back of the book is $y[n] = \frac{18}{5} 2^n$

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $y[n] = H(e^{j (\pi / 2)}) x[n]$.

Since $x[n]$ is a complex exponential, it is an eigenfunction of a LTI system with eigenvalue given by the frequency response at the frequency of $x[n]$ (which in this case is $H(e^{j (\pi/2)})$. In less fancy words, if you put a complex exponential into a LTI system, you get the same complex exponential out, except scaled by the transfer function evaluated at the frequency of the complex exponential.

Comment: Yes, thanks that makes sense for x[n] = e^j(pi/2)n but in the newer edition version of the the same question. They put x[n] = 2^n. I know that 2^n is an eigenfunction of the system, but how do I find y[n] ? Is it y[n] = H(e^jw) * x[n] ? If yes what do I substitute for w ?

Answer (score 0):

`Y[z] = H[z]X[z]`, and `y[n]` is found by taking the inverse Z-transform of `Y[z]`.

You have `H[z]` already, so the next step is finding the Z-transform of `x[n] = 2^n`. Assuming you need to find the *unilateral* Z-transform of `x[n]`, you can use a table of Z-transform pairs ([such as this one](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/EE3054/EE3054_formulas.pdf)), you can see that `X[z] = z/(z-2)`... again, this assumes that you need to take the unilateral transform or that `x[n] = (2^n)u[n]`.

Then, multiply `H[z]` by `X[z]` to get `Y[z]`. Once you have `Y[z]`, you take the inverse Z-transform and you get `y[n]`.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I appreciate it, but my problem is that x[n] = 2^n and not 2^n u[n] . I think it has to do with eigenfunction stuff. How can I find X(z) in this case, or how can I substitute 2^n into H(e^jw)